# Cycle in request. Makes request more than 15 hours

Tags: postgresql

There was a cycle. Even with a limit of 100 does not produce a result (waited more than 15 minutes)

limit 10 ~ 5 min
explain.depesz.com/s/PpO6 I can not understand. Can you help?

```
SELECT all_correct,
       real_cadastre_number,
       spec_note_factal_absent,
       ao_1_formalname,
       ao_1_node_id,
       type_property,
       exam_card,
       linked_exam_card_numbers,
       type_of_law,
       subject_of_law,
       spec_note_invalid_exam_card,
       spec_note_additional_notes
FROM analytics.import_property_objects ipo
  LEFT JOIN protected.cadastral_properties cp ON ipo.linked_exam_card_numbers = cp.id::text
WHERE ipo.all_correct ilike '%ыявленный%'
  AND ipo.cadastre_number IS NULL
  AND ipo.duplicate_exam_card_number IS NULL
  AND ipo.exam_card NOT IN (SELECT cp.id::text
                            FROM protected.cadastral_properties)
  AND (ipo.spec_note_factal_absent IS NULL 
       OR ipo.spec_note_factal_absent ilike 'НЕТ' 
       OR ipo.spec_note_factal_absent ilike 'нет')
```

Comment: What do you mean with "cycle"? As you are not using a recursive query, I don't see how this could end up in a "cycle".

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) of the query. As the query does not finish, `explain (analyze, buffers)` won't be possible. But at least a simple `explain select ...` might be helpful. Please add the plan as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).  All `create index` statements for the table involved would help as well

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/PpO6 I can not understand. Can you help?